# LogicApp OAuth API connectors and ARM deployments

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Looking for some advice here. We try to do our ARM deployments in "complete mode" most of the time. But with API connectors such as onedriveforbusiness we noticed that oauth is invalidated and someone has to go into the portal to re authorize the api connector again.

Is there a workaround available that solves this issue? Or should I just seperate the logic apps into a seperate deployment that runs in Incremental mode?

Answer (score 1):

You could configure to [**use the service principal credentials**](https://vincentlauzon.com/2018/09/25/service-principal-for-logic-app-connector/) passed to the ARM template.

The ARM Template used here was:

```
{
    "type": "microsoft.web/connections",
    "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
    "name": "[variables('Principal Data Factory Connection Name')]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": [],
    "properties": {
        "api": {
            "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location, '/managedApis/azuredatafactory')]"
        },
        "displayName": "Service Princiapl Data Factory Connection",
        "parameterValues": {
            "token:clientId": "[parameters('Service Principal App Id')]",
            "token:clientSecret": "[parameters('Service Principal Secret')]",
            "token:TenantId": "[parameters('Service Principal Tenant')]",
            "token:resourceUri": "https://management.core.windows.net/",
            "token:grantType": "client_credentials"
        }
    }
}
```

Credentials are passed in the configuration. There is no need to authorize / authenticate.

Comment: Are you sure this works for wordonlinebusiness and onedriveforbusiness? I get the following error when trying to set this up: 

Parameter 'token:clientId' is not allowed on the connection since it was not defined as a connection parameter when the API was registered..


Removing the existing API connections and then re-deploying doesn't solve the issue.